# Can we ADODB.Command objects be used as optimised evaluators / callbacks?

Tags: vba, adodb

In VBA I tried making a function as below:

```
Function DoMath(x as long)
    static command As Object
    static param As Object

    if command is nothing then
        Set command = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
        Set param = command.CreateParameter(, 3)
        command.CommandText = "?+10"
        command.Parameters.Append param
        command.prepared = True
    end if 

    'Set param value and evaluate:
    param.Value = x
    DoMath = command.Execute()
End Function
```

Unfortunately when executed this function reports:

> Run-time error '3709';
>
> The connection cannot be used to perform this operation. It is either
>   closed or invalid in this context.

This led me to believe you need a connection. But even by creating a connection to a blank database:

```
Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
conn.Open "c:/temp/tbd.mdb"

...

DoMath = command.Execute(conn)
```

This doesn't seem to resolve the error.

Any ideas how to get this function to work? Or is what I'm trying to do impossible?

Comment: Did you `Set command.ActiveConnection = conn` followed by `DoMath = command.Execute()`?

Comment: @BrianMStafford ah ha! Now I just get an error - Expected DELETE, INSERT, PROCEDURE, SELECT or UPDATE. I guess I need valid SQL... Is Procedure what I want?

Comment: I was about to respond, but it looks like you found the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Brian M Stafford for how to set up an active connection. I've improved the function to not require a MDB file.

```
Function DoMath(ByVal x As Long) As Long
    Static command As Object
    Static param As Object

    If command Is Nothing Then
        Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
        conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=c:\temp\;Extended Properties = ""text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited"""
        conn.Open

        Set command = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
        Set command.ActiveConnection = conn


        Set param = command.CreateParameter(, ADODBDataTypes.adInteger)
        command.CommandText = "SELECT ?+10"
        command.Parameters.Append param
        command.prepared = True
    End If

    'Set param value and evaluate:
    param.Value = x
    DoMath = command.Execute()(0).Value
End Function
```

Edit:

So I made this into a class and, at least using late bound functions, it was no better than using `Application.Evaluate` directly. Useful to know, but unfortunate also.

Comment: I would recommend specifying the return type for your function.

Comment: Good point, this was only a dirty test before I set up a proper class for it.

Comment: To me it looks like you're trying to implement some kind of on-the-fly calculation. If I'm correct with that assumption, you might want to have a look at [MS' Scripting Host](http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_evaluate_expressions_script_control.html) for doing so. Known limitations: only works with 32-bit Office versions (AFAIK).

Comment: Yep that's an option. I wanted to avoid that due to the limitations you've already brought up. The other solution is to write my own BNF->CNF->AST compiler and an evaluater on top of that. I'll be trying that first, and depending on whether there are any speed improvements, I'll chose which system I stick with.